# RPGLE End Field Name with an Ascending Variable

Tags: websphere, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a simple question that involves numbering the end of field names with a numeric variable.

Exp:   FIELD,X = FIELD01, FIELD,X = FIELD02, ETC....

```
             Z-ADD     1             X                 2.0
             DOU       X = 10                              
             FIELD,X         IFEQ      *BLANK                              
                             MOVE         FIELDREAD        FIELD,X
                             ENDIF 
             ADD     1           X                    

             ENDDO
```

I could do this in RPG but I'm not sure how to do this in RPGLE.  When I try to I get this error:   Entry contains data that is not valid; only valid data is used.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for array indexes in RPGLE is ARR(X).

```
FIELD(X)        IFEQ      *BLANK
```

If you're not sure about the syntax for RPGLE, try writing a little bit of code in RPG, and then use CVTRPGSRC to convert it to RPGLE.

Answer (score 0):

```
            fSomeFile  if   e           k disk             
            D ArMax           c                    10                         
            D Key1            S                   like(KeyField)                 
            D Field           S                   dim(ArMax) like(FieldRead)  

                Exsr $Sample1;
                *inlr = *on;
                return;     
       
     Begsr $Sample1;                                              
c                   z-add     1             X                 3 0 

                   setll (key1) SomeFile
                   dou x = 10;                                                
                     if Field(x) = *blank;                                    
                       reade (key1) SomeFile;                            
                       if %found(SomeFile);                                   
                         Field(x) = FieldRead;                                
                       endif;                                                 
                     endif;                                                   
                     X = X +1;                                                
                   enddo;                                                     
      Endsr;
```